# Installing C++ compiler

Tags: c++, windows, dev-c++

I am installing Dev C++ very first time. When I am trying to run a program, system is showing g++.exe has stopped running. So I can  not ultimately run or compile a program. How to solve this problem?

I am using Windows-8. Same problem is occurring in Window-XP version of the operating system.

Comment: You should paste the actual error

Comment: If possible, don't use Dev C++, it's known to be full of bugs.

Comment: @aaronman "g++.exe has stopped working" A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

Comment: @ Yu Hao Which compiler will be better?

Comment: @Samprity: The compiler is fine.  Just always make sure you have a halfway up-to-date version (the latter is true for all compilers; unlike some other (especially GUI) softwares, compilers typically always become even better with newer versions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:
http://geeksharing.blogspot.in/2013/02/dev-c-in-windows-8.html

If it doesn't solve indtall and updated Dev C++ version.
http://www.windows8downloads.com/win8-dev-c--wdoxnrth/

Comment: Thank you Roy. May be the problem is solved. I have used your first link

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use the 64-bit version of mingw.
An updated version of dev-cpp is available at https://sourceforge.net/project
s/orwelldevcpp/
via http://sourceforge.net/p/dev-cpp/discussion/48211/thread/9b1f5cb0/